# How to open Google Cloud SQL instance to see database

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have exported my google Cloud SQL instance to Google Cloud Storage. I have exported the file in the compressed format (.gz) to Cloud Storage bucket. Then after I downloaded to my system and extracted it using 7zip. How can open it in MySQL Workbench to see the database and values. Its file type is shown as instance name.

Answer (score 2):

The exported data from Cloud SQL is similar to what you get from [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). It's basically a series of SQL statements that, when you run it on another server will run all the commands to get from a clean state to the exported state.

I'm not very familiar with MySQL Workbench, but from what I've read it allows you to manage your MySQL database, browsing tables and data. So you may need to upload your exported data to another MySQL server, for example a local one running on your computer.

Note that you could also connect directly from MySQL Workbench to your Cloud SQL instance by requesting an IP for your instance and authorizing the network that you'll connect from.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly to your Cloud SQL instance. All you need to do is whitelist your IP address and connect through MySQL Workbench as if it's a normal database instance.

You can whitelist your IP by:

1. Navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/sql and select your project.
2. Go to the Connections tab and Add Network in the Public IP section.
3. Use the connection details on the Overview tab to connect

Then you can browse your database through Workbench as if it was a local instance.